# SharedPreference on different Application with different Certificate

Tags: java, android

So basically, Im working on Android project that use SharedPreference
My Apps should share a dynamic string with other Application that developed by Different Developer on Different PC (so both Application has different certificate)

can I do that? I have try with two Application in same certificate successfully, but no luck with different certificate (both application has same sharedUserId) Any Idea how to do such thing? is there any other approach to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: yes. u need to use broadcasts.

Comment: I don't think so... Because it opens up to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid), if you want to access sharedPreference of two apps they must have the same certificate.

Comment: @DroiDev okay, thanks in advance, i'll do more research

Comment: @SamuelRobert yeah I think so,I didn't noticed in the first place

Comment: @Sheshnath thanks, my bad miss the documentation

Comment: you can send information back and forth with broadcasts. sharedpref is a different beast. however, if you add in database aspect to share certain prefs, then yes, its possible.

Comment: @DroiDev using broadcast is working!! thanks, you save my day

Comment: great. @ArdyMaulana